# Bulk activate product keys in Steam

Tags: steam

After purchasing the current Humble Bundle, I wondered if it was possible to activate all of the 6 games in Steam at once, without having to do a "Product Activation" for every game.

I could probably make a script, which does this automatically, however I was wondering if there already exists a way of doing it.

Comment: You could have already activated all 6 keys in the time it took you to post this question. :P

Comment: @k1DBLITZ But who knows how many Humble Bundle's i'll purchase in the future?

Comment: @k1DBLITZ Maybe he did it for all of us. You know, for the community? For the community? For the community?

Comment: "Sadly Not"....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no official way to do this, but I wrote a simple script for Mac, that does exactly that:
https://github.com/timothybasanov/steamkeysactivator

Script uses AppleScript and could not be ported to Windows or Linux.

Comment: Works for me. Just added Chrome support ;)

Comment: +1 for the script, but there is now an official way, which you yourself noted in your [Readme](https://github.com/timofeybasanov/steamkeysactivator/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Please update your answer, this functionality was removed.

Answer (score 12):

The Steam client [is the only way to activate a Steam product key](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=33539091&postcount=3), and they only allow you to enter one product key at a time.

With some Humble Bundles, the keys are actually for a package of games, and not given individually, although the current bundle (Humble Bundle with Android 5) does not seem to give keys in this fashion.

You could potentially automate the process with some 3rd party app, although you'd have to be aware that the key authentication process can take a variable amount of time.  Also, the games default to being installed immediately, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Speaking of a 3rd party app: There's a good one in my answer below, which is smart enough to not automatically install games as it goes.

Comment: This is now incorrect; see [my answer below](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/355656/124847) for the web page at which you can activate single or multiple keys.

Answer (score 6):

For Windows, there's now the [Steam Bulk Key Activator](https://github.com/colingg/SteamBulkKeyActivator), which will read a text file of keys and plug them all in for you.  You'd have to copy the keys out of the webpage yourself, but it still saves the tediousness of the Steam aspect of it.

Comment: The Steam Bulk Key Activator no longer seems to work with the latest major Steam client redesign (2018)

Comment: @Ben That's disappointing, but not at all surprising. On the other hand, you can now redeem keys on Steam's website, which didn't use to be possible.

Answer (score 4):

**Augmented Steam Browser Extension Register Key(s) Page**

The [Steam Register Key page](https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey) (available only if you're logged in) offers just an input field to enter a single key. However, the  [Augmented Steam Browser](https://augmentedsteam.com/) extension adds an "Activate Multiple Products" button, opening a new input field in which you can enter multiple keys, one per line.

**Single-Key Auto-fill**

The key input field can be auto-filled by by appending a `key=` parameter to the URL, e.g.,

```
https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey?key=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

However, this is not entirely automatic; the user will still need to click the "Continue" button in the page brought up by this URL.

If you're redeeming Humble Bundle keys, exposing the key now shows both the key and a button that will open the above URL in a new tab, so you need only click that and "Continue" for each key.

**Multi-key Auto-fill**

The above URL can also be used for multiple product codes, though it's not quite as user-friendly. Concatenate the multiple keys in the `key=` parameter with a comma between them, e.g. `key=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX,YYYYY-YYYYY-YYYY`. This will fill the single-key input box with the comma-separated keys. This cannot be accepted as a submission ("Continue" will produce an error), but if you then push the "Activate Multiple Products" button you'll find the full contents of that field in the multi-line input box with each value on its own line, and you can submit that in the normal way by clicking "Activate Products."

Comment: This is now much faster than the Steam client registration, especially with the "Activate More" button on the second page.

Comment: This does appear to require the [Augmented Steam](https://augmentedsteam.com/) browser extension; the button only exists with that extension installed.

Comment: @demize Thanks for pointing that out! I had not realized that it was that extension that was adding this button. I've updated the answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 3):

[SteamBulkKeyActivatorScript](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VijayS1/SteamBulkKeyActivator/master/AHK/SteamBulkKeyActivator.ahk) - Right Click, Save As. Run with [AHK](https://autohotkey.com/download/ahk-install.exe)

For windows only, uses Autohotkey(AHK) to automate the steam interactions.
I've fixed the problems in it so far. You must download the [AHK source](https://github.com/VijayS1/SteamBulkKeyActivator/blob/master/AHK/SteamBulkKeyActivator.ahk). The exe's aren't compiled with the latest version.
You will need to install [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/ahk-install.exe) to make it run from the source.

I just tested it with a dozen keys and as of this posts modified date, it's fully functional.

Credit to [original author](https://github.com/colingg/SteamBulkKeyActivator/releases)

You can use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to install AHK as well (at least after you've installed chocolatey).

```
choco install autohotkey
```

Comment: Not sure why the -1, this looks like the best solution on the page

Comment: Thanks, haven't found a way to test it fully yet. Is it working with multiple keys for you?

Comment: I've updated it and now it's fully functional on windows :) !!

Answer (score -1):

No, there is currently no way to activate more than 1 product key at a time with Steam.